# How to DockerFile commands in bash instead of sh, does bash alias work for sh shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I started with dockerizing my python `hello world` program, and the dockerfile looks something like this.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Bhavani Ravi

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv
RUN apt-get install -y git

# update pip
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3.6 -m pip install wheel

RUN echo 'alias python=python3.6' >> ~/.bash_aliases
COPY hello.py .
ENTRYPOINT python hello.py
```

The problem is now when I run the image I get `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found`.
As you can see in the dockerfile, I have set up `bash_alias.` When I override `entrypoint` and run the image with `/bin/bash` and then use `python` command it works.

1. How to make the alaias work for all command environments
2. Can you run dockerfile commands in bash instead of shell

Comment: this has to do with base image you are extending, if it supports both bash and sh then you can run both

Comment: Aliases don't even work for *bash* in a noninteractive context unless explicitly enabled; they're a user portability extension only.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't setting `ENTRYPOINT python3.6 hello.py`?

Comment: Not really. I am used to setting up aliases and using them. So tried it the same way and ended up there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try wrapping each command in `/bin/bash -c "yourcommand"` if bash is available on your Docker image it will force it.

**Example**

`RUN /bin/bash -c "apt-get update"`
...
`ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "python hello.py"`